# Java parametric signature resolution

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance

Why does this code print 2.0 and not 1.0?

```
abstract class B<T extends Number> {
    abstract Number f(T j);
}

class A<T extends Number> extends B<T> {
    public Number f(Float j) {
        return 1f;
    }

    public Number f(T j) {
        return j;
    }
}

public class J {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B<Float> a = new A<>();
        Number r = a.f(2f);
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the heart of the problem here is that you have declared the variable `a` to be of type `B`. Since the `B` class has only one method, that's the one that wins. However, in your `main`, if you change the type of `a` to be of type `A`, you'll notice that it will not compile because it is ambiguous. However, if you did change the method in the class `A` to accept a primitive instead, and in the `main()` method defined the variable `a` to be of type `A`, it would result in `1.0`. I.e., the following will result in printing `1.0`:

```
class A<T extends Number> extends B<T> {
    public Number f(float j) {
        return 1f;
    }

    public Number f(T j) {
        return j;
    }
}


public class J {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A<Float> a = new A<>();
        Number r = a.f(2f);
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What are you expecting. You have only one method declared in class B:

```
abstract Number f(T j);
```

The method in the class A

```
public Number f(Float j);
```

does not override the former. They have different signatures. So the method

```
public Number f(T j) {
    return j;
}
```

gets called.

Comment: I was naively expecting it to call the method with the stricter signature `f(Float)` instead of `f(T extends Number)`

Answer (score 1):

In Your code below

```
abstract class B<T extends Number> {
 abstract Number f(T j);
}

class A<T extends Number> extends B<T> {
    public Number f(Float j) //this method does not override the superclass method

    {
        return 1f;
    }

    public Number f(T j) {
        return j;
    }
}

public class J {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B<Float> a = new A<>();
        Number r = a.f(2f);
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

when call to a.f(2f) is occured it will call the

```
public Number f(T j)
{
return j;
}
```

which return j thus output provided is 2.0

Comment: Okay, but *why* doesn't it override the superclass method?

Answer (score 0):

`float` is not the same thing as `Float`.

Auto-boxing makes it *feel* the same, but one main difference is you can't pass a `null` into a `float` parameter.

I recommend using the `@Override` annotation on your overridden methods, so the compiler will tell you if the signature is correct